# Laravel Eloquent find rows where date older than 2 days

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I'm trying to fetch rows based on the "created_at" field that are older than (for example) 2 days.

I'm using Laravel Eloquent. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Hi @fransyozef, could you please post your code?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) `subDays()` like below:

```
$data = YOURMODEL::where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDays(2)->toDateTimeString())->get();
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `whereDate()` eloquent method to run a query against dates.

```
Model::whereDate('created_at', '<=', now()->subDays(2)->setTime(0, 0, 0)->toDateTimeString())->get();
```

The `now()` is a laravel helper function to get a [carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) instance of the current date and time.

**NOTE:** We set the `time` using the `setTime()` method so that it `starts` from the beginning of the day.

**Update**: It is also possible to use `->startOfDay()`.